# Where is google api auth data being stored in node?

Tags: node.js, api, oauth-2.0

So if I use the node he client how is auth information being passed around ?

In the photo frame example it checks form data using the express body parser for a user and is authenticated function call.

But then it also calls api functions and makes requests outside the browser.

Just curious what the process is storing and where and how it’s being passed around.

Obviously the application tells Google what it is with some use of the client ids but is there a token the application has access to as well once OAuth is finished identifying the specific user account and where is that ? And how does the connecting browser keep this between server calls ? The response headers seem empty of anything of that nature. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A connecting browser is probably storing a cookie that contains some sort of token that Google has placed there through the auth process.  That cookie will then be automatically sent with future requests from the browser.

Comment: yeah thats the interesting part. In the request and responses being stored in objects within the express 4.0 event handlers, there is a field that says user, profile etc. In the request and response headers the browser reports under the debugging tools, there is a cookie set but none of the rest of that.

Comment: this is likely being handled by the passport middleware that express uses, so probably best to look there. wondering if the client secret is similar to a private rsa key in a sense.